# Perform sending operations by checkbox and prevent it in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I work with Angular 9.
I am creating a form that has a check in it, I have designed it so that when the user can click the save button that fills in the name field, but I do not know why when the checkbox is active and the user is the key Presses enter, enters operation (saveUser ()), when this should not happen.
How do I solve the problem?

```
<form [formGroup]="userF" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
        <mat-form-field class="mat_input">
            <mat-label>name</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput formControlName="firstName">
        </mat-form-field>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12">
        <mat-form-field class="mat_input">
            <mat-label>lastName</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput formControlName="lastName">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 div_checkbox">
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="delegate">delegate</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" [disabled]="!userF.valid">save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your form tag

```
<form [formGroup]="userF" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

to

```
<form [formGroup]="userF" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"  
     (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```